How does one create their own token?
I wanted to create my own token, how does one go about creating their own cryptocurrency on here and other platforms? I also wanted to create meme coins and Ai art coins is there money in doing:
1.creating a cryptocurrency
2.creating your own meme coin
3.creating and A.I. art coin
